# Test automation : element recognition differs in 2 SAP environments

Tags: ui-automation, rpa, sap-gui

We have automated tests on SAP GUI 770 using Ranorex on a SAP integration environment ; everything works well and our automation software is able to identify the different interface elements (all elements have unique IDs) :

SAP Environment 1 : the recognition works, we are able to identify the text fields with their unique names:

[image: SAP Environment 1 : the recognition works, we are able to identify the text fields with their unique names]

However, when switching to the 2nd environment, the automation software is unable to recognize the elements, making it impossible to reuse the automated tests (all elements have generic names).

SAP Environment 2 : the recognition does not work, all fields have generic "TextField" names instead of unique ones

[image: SAP Environment 2 : the recognition does not work, all fields have generic "TextField" names instead of unique ones]

Both SAP environments are accessed from the same computer, with the same user, with the same security roles.

Is there some setting that we need to change ?

I tried :

- Using an automation tool different than Ranorex (UIPath) : same difference
- Connect from a different server : same difference
- Connecting to SAP with a high-privilege user : same difference

Comment: I'm not aware of such a bug in SAP GUI 7.70 (identifying the fields but not getting the names). I don't know Ranorex/UIPath, but I would check for a bug in it. Or maybe that Ranorex/UIPath doesn't show up the fields at runtime, maybe they come from design time, and then SAP GUI Scripting is disabled on SAP environment 2? (ask the SAP system administrator to check).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

The connection must be set to High-Speed Connection instead of Low for Ranorex to work.

https://help.sap.com/docs/sap_gui_for_windows/63bd20104af84112973ad59590645513/a9b4964a706546a5acde1c25b81d3c7d.html